# Any suggestions how to create Regex for this in java for String.replaceAll()?

Tags: java, regex

My String is like this.

```
{\\\"692950841314120\\\":[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"ads_management\\\",\\\"call_count\\\":3,\\\"total_cputime\\\":1,\\\"total_time\\\":5,\\\"estimated_time_to_regain_access\\\":0}]}
```

Since the key here is a variable value I am trying to replace this 692950841314120(or the values which I get from sever) with a constant like ID. My main goal is to parse this as POJO. I have tried using..

```
string.replaceAll("^[0-9]{15}$","ID")
```

but due to Slashes I think i am not able to get the desired value. Is there any better way to do this. I know I can do below Code but I don't want any ID123 if I added extra value and distort any other info in JSON.

```
string.replaceAll("[0-9]{15}","ID")
```

Comment: Maybe replace [`^(\{\\{3}\")\d{15,}`](https://regex101.com/r/Zpe6ls/1) with `$1ID`. That way you would only remove they key at the start of the JSON and you could add more numbers to this key at the server's side.

Comment: Do you mean you want to *extract* that value?

Comment: no replace 692950841314120 with something else like ID. Its a key and is also keeps changing. I have to give @serializedName to this key in my POJO class. So that i can parse it. This value will always be 15 digit.

Comment: Then it is safer to assume the value is inisde ``\"`` and ``\":``. Use `.replaceAll("(\\\\\")[0-9]{15}(\\\\\":)", "$1ID$2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safer to assume the value is inisde `\"` and `\":`.

You can then use

```java
.replaceAll("(\\\\\")[0-9]{15}(\\\\\":)", "$1ID$2")
```

The regex is `(\\")[0-9]{15}(\\":)` and it means:

- `(\\")` - match and capture `\"` substring into Group 1
- `[0-9]{15}` - fifteen digits
- `(\\":)` - Group 2: a `\":` substring.

The `$1` and `$2` are placeholders holding the Group 1 and 2 values.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, if you have a valid JSON string, you should *parse* it using something like GSON, rather than using regex.  That being said, if you must use regex, you could try removing the starting and ending anchors:

```
string.replaceAll("[0-9]{15}", "ID")
```

Or maybe use double quotes instead:

```
string.replaceAll("\"[0-9]{15}\"", "ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "A word boundary" `\b`.

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "{\\\"692950841314120\\\":"
        + "[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"12345678901234567890\\\","
        + "\\\"call_count\\\":3,"
        + "\\\"total_cputime\\\":1,"
        + "\\\"total_time\\\":5,"
        + "\\\"estimated_time_to_regain_access\\\":0}]}";
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\b[0-9]{15}\\b", "ID"));
}
```

output:

```
{\"ID\":[{\"type\":\"12345678901234567890\",\"call_count\":3,\"total_cputime\":1,\"total_time\":5,\"estimated_time_to_regain_access\":0}]}
```